# Possible vector solution for synthetic geometry involving parallelogram and triangle sharing centroid?

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB=30$, $BC=51$, $CA=63$. Points $P$ and $Q$ lie on $\overline{BC}$, $R$ lies on $\overline{CA}$, and $S$ lies on $\overline{AB}$ such that $PQRS$ is a parallelogram, and the center of $PQRS$ coincides with the centroid of $\triangle ABC$. What is the area of parallelogram $PQRS$? *(Source: CMC)*

There is a synthetic solution involving half the height from $SR$ to $PQ$ being $1/3$ the height from $A$ to $BC$, but I'm looking for a solution involving vectors or complex geometry to learn how to apply them in this kind of problem.

I've tried some things that haven't lead very far. $\cos A = 3/5$ by the Law of Cosines and that seems to be the only nice angle, so I tried scaling the sides, then setting $w = \mathrm{cis}A$ and $|z| = 1$ s.t. $10z=AB$, $21zw=AC$ but that doesn't really help since we already know the side lengths. I tried doing the same instead with the parallelogram, but my angle chasing didn't get very far.

By the way, the answer is

> 336.

I would most appreciate an analytic solution not entirely depending on the insight that half the height from $SR$ to $PQ$ is $1/3$ the height from $A$ to $PQ$, since the easiest step to go from there would not be the proceed with an analytic solution, but just to use Heron's and complete the problem from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pure vector solution is possible. We let
$c:=\overrightarrow{AC}$,
$b:=\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\ b,c$ be the basis and $A$ be the origin meaning if I write $X=xb+yc$ it reads $\overrightarrow{AX}=xb+yc$ (for an arbitrary point $X$ and scalars $x,y$). The picture:
[image]
It's given that
$$\begin{cases}
S=yb\\R=xc\\R-S=t(b-c)\\
P=uc+(1-u)b\\Q=vc+(1-v)b\\
R-S=Q-P\\Q-R=P-S\\\frac{Q+S}{2}=\frac{0+b+c}{3}
\end{cases}$$
It's a purely linear vector problem, meaning we don't take constraints $|b|=30,\,|c|=63,\,|b-c|=51$ at all for a while. Solving the system we get $$\begin{cases}
x=\frac13\\y=\frac13\\u=\frac13\\v=\frac23
\end{cases}$$
Now, as $P,\,Q,\,R,\,S$ are known along with $b^2=30^2$, $c^2=63^2$ and $\langle b,c\rangle = \frac12\left(|b|^2+|c|^2-|b-c|^2\right)$ we can express the area of $PQRS$ as
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Area}_{PQRS}&=
|\overrightarrow{SR}|\cdot |\overrightarrow{SP}|
\cdot\left|\sin\angle RSP\right|\\
&=|\overrightarrow{SR}|\cdot |\overrightarrow{SP}|
\cdot\sqrt{1-\cos^2\angle RSP}\\
&=|\overrightarrow{SR}|\cdot |\overrightarrow{SP}|
\cdot\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{
\langle\overrightarrow{SR},\overrightarrow{SP}\rangle}{
|\overrightarrow{SR}|\cdot |\overrightarrow{SP}|}
\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{
\overrightarrow{SR}^2\cdot\overrightarrow{SP}^2-
\left(\langle\overrightarrow{SR},\overrightarrow{SP}\rangle\right)^2
}
\end{align*}
hence we can find [the answer](https://tio.run/##bY7LasMwEEX3/oosJXvkJ@1CZn6hFLI0MYyEoYG4sSXZJBh/uztOTVddzeFwuXd6Cl9dT@FqadvIalws5GtNhonArHXkND5isrXX@IzJ1NGgcWKRiEJN8mVGjfNh5l/jc43n@23umsUpjxhiQVaRkTCqAZEdg0McGMSYeJmViBxJOJJVQDYli/hetSWQSckgVjnzUZIeF/GtaMsVov1VsPCAJwSYYF4vdUSuI40fd9c3vHmJX@R3Oo8uNIUSgj13sZOZ@CcoZVty0ae7fodmrztl6cnnf2rZ9/a1w2/bDw) of $336$.

---

**Edit**: how do we solve the linear system. Okay, the answer on "how did I solve it" is "I didn't, WA did", but it should be solvable). I'll leave this
$$\begin{cases}
S=yb\\R=xc\\
P=uc+(1-u)b\\Q=vc+(1-v)b
\end{cases}$$
rather as "definitions" of $P,\,Q,\,R,\,S$ and will work with the rest of the system.
$$\begin{cases}
R-S=t(b-c)\\
R-S=Q-P\\
Q-R=P-S\\
\frac{Q+S}{2}=\frac{0+b+c}{3}
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
xc-yb=t(b-c)\\
xc-yb=vc+(1-v)b-(uc+(1-u)b)\\
vc+(1-v)b-xc=uc+(1-u)b-yb\\
3(vc+(1-v)b+yb)=2(b+c)
\end{cases}$$
As $b,\,c$ form a basis, each vector has the only representation as a linear combination of basis vectors, which means that the coefficients of $b$ and $c$ (seperately) of each LHS and RHS of the system are equal, i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
x=t\\
-y=-t\\
x=v-u\\
-y=(1-v)-(1-u)\\
v-x=u\\
1-v=(1-u)-y\\
3v=2\\
3((1-v)+y)=2
\end{cases}$$
again we could feed it to [WA (click to see the result)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dt%2C+-y%3D-t%2C+x%3Dv-u%2C+-y%3D%281-v%29-%281-u%29%2C+v-x%3Du%2C+1-v%3D%281-u%29-y%2C+3v%3D2%2C+3%28%281-v%29%2By%29%3D2) or perform Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Should I add the explicit computations of $x,y,u,v$ and $\operatorname{Area}_{PQRS}$?

Comment: The answer makes sense, but how do you solve the system?

Comment: @DavidDong please see the edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use $BC$ is the $x$ axis, say with $B$ being the origin. Then the coordinates of the points are $A=(x_a,y_a)$, $B=(0,0)$, $C=(x_c,0)$, $P=(x_p,0)$, $Q=(x_q,0)$, $R=(x_r,y_r)$, $S=(x_s,y_s)$. We know $PQRS$ is parallelogram, so $y_r=y_s$ and $x_r=x_s+(x_q-x_p)$. Then the center of the parallelogram along $x$ is at $$\frac12(x_q+x_s)=\frac12(x_r+x_p)$$ The $y$ position of the center of parallelogram is at $$\frac 12 (y_s+y_q)=\frac12 y_s$$
The center of the triangle is at $$\left(\frac{x_a+x_c}3, \frac{y_a}3\right)$$
From here you get $$y_s=\frac23 y_a$$ and since $S$ is on $BA$ you have $$\frac{y_s-y_b}{x_s-x_b}=\frac{y_a-y_b}{x_a-x_b}$$ or $$\frac{y_s}{x_s}=\frac{y_a}{x_a}$$
Therefore $x_s=\frac23 x_a$.
Similarly $R$ is on $AC$ and therefore $x_r-x_c=\frac 23(x_a-x_c)$ or $$x_r=\frac23x_a+\frac13 x_c$$

Now the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $A_3=\frac 12 y_a\cdot x_c$, and the area of the parallelogram is $$A_4=y_s(x_r-x_s)=\frac 23y_a\left(\frac23 x_a+\frac 13 x_c-\frac 23 x_a\right)=\frac 29 y_a x_c$$
From here $$\frac{A_4}{A_3}=\frac49$$
This is valid for any triangle. Now use Heron or any method to calculate $A_3=756$, and you get $$A_4=\frac 49 756=336$$

Comment: Taking $A$ as the origin would be more convinient

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Maybe. But then you need to add $y_b=y_c\ne 0$. Yo get at least 3 non zero coordinates anyway